# Error: The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

[image]

I paste the numbers from a different sheet and there's an error showing next to each cell in column A. I
I don't want to ignore the errors manually each time, so I tried to apply the following VBA code:

```
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False
```

And it is working but then, when I click on a cell, the number converts to a number and removes "0" from requests.

How to handle it?

Comment: If you are storing the values as "numbers", the stored value will NOT have leading zero's.  If you need the leading zero to be present, you must leave it as text. If you only need to **display** a leading zero, and if all of the numbers have eight (8) digits, then custom format the cell as `00000000`.

Comment: What error are you referring at? What format would you like the cells in discussion to have? Should I suppose, looking at the code you tried, that you need numbers? If yes, the above comment clearly states what is it above. In order to re-format all the range as `General`, the best solution, I think, would be to use `TextToColumns`. Manual, or in code...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of VBA code, you can turn off error checking for that particular issue in Excel's settings (Excel Options > Formulas > Error Checking Rules), but that will affect all workbooks.

If you only want to turn it off in a single workbook, then perhaps instead of copy/paste for those data, you can use the TEXT() formula to force the format to text in the new cells. E.g. `=TEXT([@[SCHOOL_ID_CODE]],"00000000")` will take the School ID Codes from my table and display them in 8-digit text format with leading zeroes - even if Excel decides it wants to helpfully remove them from the original column.